# What's the best way to migrate from MYSQL to Elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, migration, logstash

I am going to migrate MYSQL logs (Millions of records) to ELK and I'm wondering what is the best way to do it.

Should I just create a single index for all the records(sql database) or should I create different index per database?

Or if there's a better way to do it, can you please suggest?

Btw, I am new to ELK and the forum is not quite helpful.. Sorry.

I already tried migrating a single db with at least 1000 records and it worked.

Comment: If you have the date available, I think it a good idea to separate the logs in date-base index, it makes cleaning the data much easier.

Comment: Create different index,dont forget id are unique by index. Dont forget to set your mappings first.  Are your logs simular or are they really different, do you need to querry them together or by category?

Comment: @LeBigCat thank you for your response.. The logs are really different and I will be needing them to query at the same time.. Will be using join syntax, actually..

Comment: @baudsp Yes, I do have a date column in the table.. What do you mean exactly by date-base index? Can you explain on how will I do it? Thank you again.

Comment: When using the elasticsearch plugin, when configuring the index name, you can specify a index name with `%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, which will use the date in the `timestamp` field of the event (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index)). By default the timpestamp is the date at which the event arrives on logstash, but it can be overwritten with [mutate#replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace)

Comment: By using `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, you'll have index called logstash-2019.03.30, logstash-2019.03.31, logstash-2019.04.01..., with each containing the logs which timestamp are of this date. You'll have to use the date from your date column so that it's the rigth date that's used.

Answer (score 0):

One way to migrate data that also supports query based results would be to use the JDBC input plugin within Logstash.
The index architecture you choose to migrate to depends on what kind of use cases you are looking at / what kind of analysis you are planning to do. A direct migration might not help because of Elasticsearch being indexed and non-relational, as opposed to MySQL. You might want to de-normalise your data before pushing into Elasticsearch.